# Looping through an array with objects to retrieve properties

Tags: javascript

I'm working on Free Code Camp's curriculum and am stuck on a certain project. I don't think my loop is working correctly, because it's not retrieving the information it's supposed to.

The instructions are as follows:

> We have an array of objects representing different people in our
>   contacts lists.
>
> A lookUpProfile function that takes firstName and a property (prop) as
>   arguments has been pre-written for you.
>
> The function should check if firstName is an actual contact's
>   firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
>
> If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
>
> If firstName does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such
>   contact"
>
> If prop does not correspond to any valid properties then return "No
>   such property"

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(firstName)) {
        if (contacts[i].firstname === prop) {
          return contacts[i].firstName;
        }
        else {
          return "No such property";
        }
      }
      else {
        return "No such contact";
      }
  }
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

I'm not sure where my problem lies unfortunately, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This code doesnt work, if I have a function like lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");  ....the code doesnt check whether the name Kristian exists.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things not right with your code.

First, the `hasOwnProperty` does not do what you think it does. Read up on [the docs on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Furthermore, Javascript is case sensitive, and reports undefined properties to be value of type `undefined`. Therefore the following `if` does not do exactly what you want, without yielding an error.

```
if (contacts[i].firstname === prop) {
    return contacts[i].firstName;
}
```

Note the different casing for the first**N**ame property.

Try for example the following snippet:

```
console.log(typeof {}.doesNotExist);
```

It will show up as `undefined`.

Last but not least: you would probably benefit more from learning how to debug than these answers :) Some simple debugging can be done by adding `console.log` calls anywhere in your code. Better even is to leverage debugging of your browser, or debugging using an IDE.

Comment: Thank you for explaining those errors, makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Please use firstName inside quotes when you are checking for hasOwnProperty. Moreover, JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. firstName and firstname are considered different variable. You are using   *if (contacts[i].firstname === prop)* in your code whereas it should actually be   *if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName)*. And, Please compare the right property as well. You were comparing firstName to props, which I don't understand what you actually want to do.

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty('firstName')) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === prop) {
          return contacts[i].firstName;
        }
        else {
          return "No such property";
        }
      }
      else {
        return "No such contact";
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {
          return contacts[i][prop];
        }
        else {
          return "No such contact";
        }
      }
      else {
        return "No such property";
      }
  }
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
var data = lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
console.log(data);
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yp8b2tg7/

**All requirements are fullfilled :**

- If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
- If firstName does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such
  contact"
- If prop does not correspond to any valid properties then return "No
  such property"

Answer (score 0):

Rohit's answer is correct in most cases.

If I run the test case,

```
var data = lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes");
```

it would return

```
"No such contact"
```

which is not the expected result.

The problem is with the 'else' part of

```
if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {}
```

While the first item in the 'contacts' is checked, return the value only when a matching contacts is found. Else ignore it and loop through ll the items in the 'contacts'. Once everything is done, we can return 'No such contacts'

I have modified the function a bit like below - try this,

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
   for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
         }
      }
      else {
         return "No such property";
      }
   }
   return "No such contact";
}

var data = lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes");
console.log(data);
```

Updated JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z5ww2nbv/

Answer (score 0):

It is best to check for the property first, as in Rohit's answer. If you would like to check for the name first, you could try this, although less elegant:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
var count = 0;
for (i=0; i <contacts.length; i++) {
 if (contacts[i].firstName == name) {
   if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
     return contacts[i][prop];
   }
   else {
     return "No such property";
   }
 } else {
   count += 1;
 } 
}
if (count == contacts.length) {
  return "No such contact";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){      
    var i, found=0;
    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)  {
        if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {
            found=1;
            if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        }
    }
    return "No such contact"; //return this if contact not found
}
```